# Configuring Hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

How to tell to my Spring and here is my hibernate.cf.xml... I am getting this error. I have not configured anything in my application-context.xml

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException
Cause: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:507)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1154)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:193)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.ja
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:266)
        at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:476)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at your.intermedix.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:18)
        at your.intermedix.persistence.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
        at your.intermedix.services.ContactSerImpl.saveContact(ContactSerImpl.java:17)
        at your.intermedix.MyVaadinApplication.buttonClick(MyVaadinApplication.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:487)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1411)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1433)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
        at your.intermedix.persistence.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
```

Comment: Is hibernate.cfg.xml in your application classpath?

Answer (score 2):

If you are configuring Hibernate with Spring then in session factory you cans pecify location to your file this way, if its not the case please update your question with sufficient information

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="configLocation">
<value>file:src/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring with Hibernate, then you can do something like this.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="YourClass"
        class="com.YourClass.
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="DbSessionFactory" />
        </property>     
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/yourdb</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>

    <bean id="DbSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref local="dataSource"/>
        </property>     
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>conf/hibernate/UserMapping.hbm.xml</value>               
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect </prop>      
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"> true </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```